# functions.runWith is not a function using firebase cloud functions when deploying

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Got this error when trying to deploy functions with runWith option

```
functions.runWith({ memory: '1GB' })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out at least version 2.0.1 of firebase-functions is required.

to fix this

```
npm i firebase-functions@latest
npm i firebase-admin@latest
```

Keep in mind 2.x.x introduces some breaking changes.